# Started Seeing CORS Issue with our Application

Tags: cors

We started to experience CORS errors in our application, but only when header "Cache-Control" is used with any value. Any clues on how this header could impact cross-domain calls?

The code has not been modified in a while so the error is recent.

Answer (score 0):

The `Cache-Control` header in HTTP is used to specify directives for caching mechanisms in both requests and responses. While this header itself shouldn't directly cause Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issues, its presence may be related to other aspects of your application behavior that trigger CORS errors.

Here are a few potential reasons why you might be experiencing CORS issues when using the `Cache-Control` header:

1. **Preflight Requests**: When making certain types of requests (e.g., with specific HTTP methods or custom headers), the browser may send a preflight request (OPTIONS) to check if the actual request (e.g., GET, POST) is safe to send. If the preflight request fails due to CORS, the actual request won't be made. The presence of the `Cache-Control` header might trigger a preflight request in certain scenarios.
2. **Server Configuration**: The server might be configured to respond with the Cache-Control header in a way that conflicts with CORS policies. For example, if the server sends a response that allows caching but is not configured to allow cross-origin requests, it could lead to issues.
3. **CORS Headers**: Ensure that your server includes the necessary CORS headers in its responses, such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. The combination of these headers dictates which origins are allowed, what methods are permitted, and which headers can be used.
4. **Browser Security Policies**: Browsers have security policies in place to prevent malicious cross-origin requests. The presence of the Cache-Control header might trigger these policies, especially if the combination of headers and other settings doesn't meet the browser's expectations.

If you provide more details about the specific CORS error message you are encountering and the server setup, I might be able to provide more targeted assistance.

Comment: We are running .NET Core with Kestrel web server running on LInux in Azure Kubernetes Service. This application has been up for a while, no changes. The UI makes multiple API requests but for some reason only 1 fails, and it only fails when Cache-Control header is added to request. Other requests work fine, with or without the Cache-Control header.

Comment: We do enable CORS headers in the code for our backend app

services.AddCors(options =>
                options.AddPolicy("cors-policy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(
                            "<list of our sites>")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                    })
            );